# zabbix frontend webinterface gives error 404 (ubunutu server 14.04)

Tags: linux, apache, frontend, zabbix, ubuntu-14.04

I can't open the zabbix frontend URL via
http://*zabbixservername*/zabbix

### Error 404 is given:

Not Found

The requested URL /zabbix was not found on this server.

### Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at *ipaddress* Port 80

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-27-generic x86_64)

I installed Zabbix server following Zabbix instructions for Ubuntu 14.04 at:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/installation/install_from_packages
(bottom section of the page)

Though the follwowing file was not created:
/etc/apache2/conf.d/zabbix.conf

But I did edit regional settings in:
/etc/zabbix/apache.conf

After that I also copied the apache.conf to /etc/apache2/conf.d/zabbix.conf
restarted apache, but gave no result

Apache is running; when I go to http://*zabbixservername*/, I get the Apache default welcome page.

Also zabbix-server process is running on the server.

This is what the Apache acces.log says when I try to enter the frontend http://*zabbixservername*/zabbix

[04/Jun/2014:14:42:54 +0200] "GET /zabbix HTTP/1.1" 404 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"

I would guess the problem lies somewhere within the communication between Apache and Zabbix?
If so... I don't know how to check and/or fix that...

Looking for some guidance here.
Additional information can be provided.

Answer (score 12):

Though xunil's answer is right, let me correct it a little bit corresponding to the Ubuntu 14.04 and it's Apache 2.4

```
ln -s /etc/zabbix/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/zabbix.conf
```

It will put a symlink to the Apache config folder...

```
a2enconf zabbix.conf
service apache2 reload
```

...and these will reload the server to pick up the new configurations.

Comment: +1 This worked for me, @xunil paths are slightly off

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/zabbix-frontend-php/examples/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/zabbix.conf

sudo a2enconf zabbix.conf

sudo service apache2 reload
```